# How to show Parent Directory and all its Sub-Directories as a Tree

Tags: mysql

A "HR" Department is created and it will have sub-directories.
I need to show their sub-directories like below tree as well as their all directory and sub-directories created in future.

Tree structure:

Dir1
Dir1-->Dir2
Dir1-->Dir2-->Dir3
Dir4

This would be done in mysql.

[image]

Comment: You can implement  it using a [Nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) structure

Comment: @Alon, Could you please write the sql for me to help me out.

Comment: First, give us your MySQL version. If you are on version 8, there are new functionalities that allows to do this efficiently

Comment: current version is 8 but may need to deploy it in the lower version in future according to the requirement.

Comment: @ThomasG When you said _If you are on version 8, there are new functionalities that allows to do this efficiently_, are you talking about `WITH RECURSIVE`?

Comment: indeed, a CTE. You will find inspiration here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/